# using SESSIONS passing values to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stuck on passing values from a form on one page to (confirm.aspx) another page. Would someone help me out with this?  I am not looking for some one to code my program because I have done much of the work already.  Here is what I have, Default.aspx as three values that I need to pass to Confirm.aspx. This is what I have for the Default.aspx.

```asp
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1>Price quotation</h1>
    <label>Sales price</label>       
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSalesPrice" runat="server" CssClass="entry">100</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSalesPrice" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" CssClass="validator">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSalesPrice" Display="Dynamic" MaximumValue="1000" MinimumValue="10" Type="Double" CssClass="validator">Must be from 10 to 1000</asp:RangeValidator><br /><br />
    <label>Discount percent</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDiscountPercent" runat="server" CssClass="entry">20</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDiscountPercent" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" CssClass="validator">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDiscountPercent" Display="Dynamic" MaximumValue="50" MinimumValue="10" Type="Double" CssClass="validator">Must be from 10 to 50</asp:RangeValidator><br />
    <label>Discount amount</label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblDiscountAmount" runat="server" CssClass="result" ></asp:Label><br /><br />
    <label>Total price</label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat="server" CssClass="result" ></asp:Label><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate" OnClick="btnCalculate_Click" CssClass="button" />
    <asp:Button ID="ConfirmButton" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Confirm" PostBackUrl="~/Confirm.aspx" OnClick="ConfirmButton_Click" />
    <p><asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" /></p>
</form>
```

Code Behind the Default.aspx

```java
protected void ConfirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Session["Sales"] = txtSalesPrice.Text;
    Response.Redirect("Confirm.aspx");
    Session["Amt"] = lblDiscountAmount.Text;
    Response.Redirect("Confirm.aspx");
    Session["Total"] = lblTotalPrice.Text;
    Response.Redirect("Confirm.aspx");
}
```

Confirm.aspx

```asp
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1>Quotation confirmation</h1>
    <label>Sales price</label><asp:Label ID="lblSalesPrice" runat="server" CssClass="result"></asp:Label><%=Session["Sales"] %><br /><br />
    <label>Discount amount</label><asp:Label ID="lblDiscountAmount" runat="server" CssClass="result"><%=Session["Amt"] %></asp:Label><br /><br />
    <label>Total price</label><asp:Label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat="server" CssClass="result"><%=Session["Price"] %></asp:Label><br />
    <h2>Send confirmation to</h2>
    <label>Name</label>       
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="entry"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" CssClass="validator">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
    <label>Email address</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="entry"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" CssClass="validator">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send Quotation" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnReturn" runat="server" Text="Return" PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnReturn_Click" />
    <p><asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" /></p>
</form>
```

If someone would take the time out and review what I have here.  I would appreciate. There is nothing pertinent on the code behind on the Confirm.aspx.cs.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering if I use the <asp:TextBox ID="txtSales" runat="server" Text='<%# Session["Sales"] %>' > do I use that in my Default page or my Confirm page?  If I use that in my Default page then what will get the values in my Confirm page?  Just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Code behind default.aspx

```
   protected void ConfirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Session["Sales"] = txtSalesPrice.Text;

Session["Amt"] = lblDiscountAmount.Text;

Session["Total"] = lblTotalPrice.Text;
Response.Redirect("Confirm.aspx");
}
```

And you get value in another page like this
In .cs

```
txtSales.text = Session["Sales"];
```

In .aspx

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSales" runat="server" Text='<%# Session["Sales"] %>' >
```

Comment: I appreciate you offering your logic, but when I run the program I am getting txtSales.text = Session["Sales"] where the value is suppose to show.  Same thing for the DiscountAmount and TotalPrice.

Comment: I used in my Default.aspx this <asp:TextBox ID="txtSalesPrice" runat="server" CssClass="entry" Text='<%# Session["Sales"] %>'>100</asp:TextBox>.  But there is nothing in my Confirm to catch the values?  Is that right.